# Npm Library with dependencies varying from one project to another

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, dependencies, nestjs

I work in typescript with npm dependencies

*Theory:*

Let's say a library **A**
And two projects **B** and **C**

My library **A** uses dependencies needed in **B** but not in **C**

How to install this dependency in project **B** but not in **C** without having a compilation error ?

```
project B
 |----library A
 |----library D

project C
 |----library A

library A
 |----library D
```

*Practical:*

As I am probably on the wrong track, here is the concrete case!
I am on a project with an **Angular front-end** and a **NestJs back-end**.
I have created a common library in which there are DTOs. I want to use the `@ApiProperty()` annotation from `@nestjs/swagger`. But I don't want to install all `@nestjs/swagger` dependencies on my **Angular front-end**.

In this case, I saw that the Swagger pluggin could help me:
https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin 
But after testing, it doesn't work on node_modules files

```
api
 |----dto library
 |----@nestjs/swagger

front
 |----dto library

dto library
 |----@nestjs/swagger (for annotation)
```

Comment: no one has found a solution or a lead?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get that working without some custom build script that reads files in your `dto` lib, removes all `@nestjs/swagger` imports and decorators, and writes interfaces into another library folder, from which you can import them in your `front` app. Or somehow mock Swagger in the `front` app so that the decorators would be no-op functions, not imported from the actual Swagger lib.

**Simpler way:**

Let your `dto` lib only have pure interfaces. Don't import Swagger or anything there. Just export interfaces.

Then you can import the interfaces in your `front`app, and in your `api` app you implement the interfaces into classes and add all the swagger decorators. And why not toss `class-validator` in there too, it's awesome with Nest's ValidationPipe.

Comment: Sidenote, I tried to do `Or somehow mock Swagger...` long time ago, using tsconfig.json paths to import Typeorm, Swagger etc. server libs from my own location instead of node_modules but never got that to really work. Since then a couple times I've used the first method mentioned, but nowadays I usually just go for the simple method because it's not so bad even though there is some repetition. 

If someone has done this successfully, please let me know   =)

Comment: Mmm ok so I touched a difficult point... Yes the simple way is not so bad, but as I wanted to create multiple micro-services which may use this library with this swagger tool. I will dig a little more to read the files in the library, if I find I will post it for sure! But I start to lose hope ^^

Tank's for the answer

Comment: One shared lib for interfaces, other shared lib for implemented classes for server apps then.

Comment: Yes I thought of this solution too, but also if you modify a dto, you have to modify two libraries...